# trying to convert date to timestamp, but when I convert it back to a date, the date is no consistent

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

```
let timestamp = (NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (timestamp))

print(NSDate())   // 2016-08-20 18:24:17 +0000
print(timestamp) //  1471717652.15506
print(date)     //   2047-08-21 18:24:17 +0000
```

How can I make the timestamp consistent?

Comment: The output you show for the code you posted doesn't really match. The two epochs are different by 31 years so the 1st and 3rd print statements should show dates that are 31 years different, not one day.

Comment: @rmaddy: 2016-08-20 and 2047-08-21 do differ by 31 years :)

Comment: @MartinR Ugh. Reading comprehension failure.

Comment: my bad guys ill be more clear next time

Answer (score 5):

Your question isn't entirely clear but I suspect you want the first and third `print` statements to be the same. Assuming that is true, you need to fix either the 1st or 2nd line of code to use the same epoch.

The 1st line uses the "1970" epoch. The 2nd line uses the Cocoa "reference date" epoch. They are not the same. Change one of the two lines to match the other.

You want either:

```
let timestamp = (NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:timestamp)
```

or:

```
let timestamp = (NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:timestamp)
```